# Add handler to runtime-created control

Tags: vb6, runtime, controls, handler, addition

I found in StackOverflow some vb.net code written by "PaRiMaL RaJ". i want the same think but i must convert this code to work on VB6.
can you help me please???

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' creating control
    Dim btn1 As Button = New Button()
    Dim btn2 As Button = New Button()

    btn1.Parent = Me
    btn1.Name = "btn1"
    btn1.Top = 10
    btn1.Text = "Btn1"

    btn2.Parent = Me
    btn2.Name = "btn2"
    btn2.Top = 50
    btn2.Text = "Btn2"

    'adding handler for click event
    AddHandler btn1.Click, AddressOf HandleDynamicButtonClick
    AddHandler btn2.Click, AddressOf HandleDynamicButtonClick


End Sub

Private Sub HandleDynamicButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)

    If btn.Name = "btn1" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Btn1 clicked")
    ElseIf btn.Name = "btn2" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Btn2 Clicked")
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a control array. Add a button to your form in the designer and set its `Index` property to `0`. You can hide the button if you don't want it to be visible.

Then, when you want to dynamically add more buttons at run-time, just use the `Load` statement.

For example, if your button was named `Command1`:

```
Load Command1(1)                     ' Create a new button
Command1(1).Move 50, 50, 1500, 500   ' Set its size and position
Command1(1).Caption = "New Button"   ' Give it a caption
Command1(1).Visible = True           ' Make it visible
```

The button will use the same event handlers as your original button:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click(Index As Integer)

    ' Print the caption of the clicked button...
    Debug.Print Command1(Index).Caption

End Sub
```